# Is every finitely generated linearly compact module Artinian?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, compactness, artinian

We know that every Artinian module is linearly compact. Is the converse true? Is this true that every finitely generated linearly compact module is Artinian? If not, is there example of a finitely generated module that be linearly compact but it is not Artinian? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any ring with a Morita duality is linearly compact in the discrete topology. See §24 and §30 in the book by Anderson-Fuller “Rings and Categories of Modules” for the definition.

It is a classical result by Müller that a ring with Morita duality is linearly compact in the discrete topology (B. J. Müller, *Linear compactness and Morita duality*, J. Algebra **16** (1970), pp. 60–66).

A simple example is the ring $F[[x]]$ of formal power series over a field $F$; see Example 10 in [this paper by Weimin Xue](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/48749F6B29FF30252D3CF75699EA12FF/S0004972700016051a.pdf/on_morita_duality.pdf) (Bull. Austral. Math. Soc. **49** (1994), pp. 35–46). Such a ring is clearly not Artinian, but it is linearly compact in the discrete topology (and it is obviously finitely generated).

Comment: Thanks. it is true. But i am confused with this and Lemma 7.3 of Fuch' book. "Modules over non-Noetherian domains". Lemma 7.3. A module that is linearly compact in the discrete topology is finitely cogenerated, so it has finite Goldie dimension.It also has finite dual Goldie dimension.